# Uploading file version - Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, file-upload, version-history

I have a library with versioned files. I have versioned files prepared for uploading (1 version = 1 file). How do I create new version? Do I just set file's Content property and Update it? Please share your experinces, thanks

edit: I have something like this:

```
File1|v1
File1|v2
File1|v4
File2|v2
File2|v5
```

So I have missing versions. Is it possible to set file version when uploading (item's field?)? If not, I will fill missing version with previous/next versions, for example File2|v1 will be filled with File2|v2.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "prepared for uploading"? Do you mean you have documents outside of SharePoint that have multiple versions? Do the different versions of a file have the same name?

Comment: Yes, I have files outside of Sharepoint. I'll upload them programatically, so I can give them any name. Files are stored in a DB and I know which file is which version.

Comment: So, you want to keep the original version numbers and not have SharePoint assign the version numbers in order, right?

Comment: If possible yes, but otherwise I will fill gaps with other versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to programmatically assign the version number, but if it is OK to let SharePoint assign the version number...

With the server version of the method:

```
SPFileCollection.Add(urlOfFile, fileContent, overwrite);
```

if you pass in overwrite=true and the document library has versioning turned on, I think it will create a new version of the document. (That's the behavior through the browser.) I assume the Client Object Model version of the method would behave the same way.

```
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
fci.Url = urlOfFile;
fci.Content = fileContent;
fci.Overwrite = true;
folder.files.Add(fci);
```

So, as long as you upload the files in the correct order of their versions, SharePoint should create each version for you.

Comment: But will it create a minor or major number of version?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should adhere to however you set it up on your document library under Library Settings > Versioning settings.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little code sample that will simulate versioning of a file

```
public File changeDocumentVersion(string version,File file){
    string [] versions = version.Split(new char[]{'.'});
    int minor = Int32.Parse(versions[1]);
    int major = Int32.Parse(versions[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < major; i++)
    {
        file.CheckOut();
        file.CheckIn("versioning", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < minor; i++)
    {
        file.CheckOut();
        file.CheckIn("versioning", CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
        file.Context.Load(file);
        file.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have enabled versioning (found under list/library settings, then versioning) enabled SP will take care of the versioning for you.

Comment: This means that if I get a document with Client Object Model, change it's Content property and do Update on this document, it will automatically create new version?